# Prove that $\forall n \geq 1$ there exists a field containing $n$ subfields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Then Find a minimal finite field containing exactly 8 subfields.  I assume that the last part of this question will be more obvious once I have the proof down.

I know that a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ is contained in the finite field $\mathbb{F}_r$ if and only if there exists a prime $p$ and integers $n$ and $m$ such that $q=p^m$, $r=p^n$, and $m|n$. This follows because $\mathbb{F}_r$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_q$, and so will have $q^d$ elements for some $d$; and because finite fields must have order a power of a prime.  How does this mean that there is always a field that contains n elsements?

Comment: "Containing exactly $n $ subfields" and "containing exactly $n$ elements" are two very different things. The first can be found and is a reasonable thing to ask for, the second cannot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $r=p^m$. Then $\mathbb{F}_r$ contains a (unique) subfield with $s$ elements iff $s=p^k$ where $k$ is a divisors of $m$. Thus $\mathbb{F}_r$ contains exactly $n$ subfield iff the number $d(m)$ of divisors of $m$ equals $n$. So, for example, for $m=2^{n-1}$ the corresponding field $\mathbb{F}_r$ contains exactly $n$ subfields.

Comment: Do you have any insight on how to do the second part of the problem?  Finding the minimal finite field containing exactly 8 subfields?

Comment: @JensSchwaiger it seems to me this should be a proof by induction. Also, I second John Smith's follow-up question about how to find the minimal finite field containing exactly 8 subfields.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you don’t mean “exactly eight *proper* subfields”, I suppose you want the smallest number with precisely eight divisors, and that’s $30$. So $\Bbb F_{2^{30}}$ should fit the bill.

Comment: what do you mean by not proper subfields?

Comment: The big field is not a proper subfield of itself.